# Is possible to make mypy accept dynamic generated classes as valid types?

Tags: python, mypy

I have this code to encode ADTs in python

```
from dataclasses import make_dataclass

def adt(datatype, *ctrs: str):
    basecls = type(datatype, (), {})
    klass = lambda x: x.split()[0]
    fields = lambda x: x.split()[1:]
    clss = (make_dataclass(klass(cls),
                           bases=(basecls,),
                           fields=fields(cls))
            for cls in ctrs)
    return (basecls, *clss)

# Just call the adt function passing the
# constructors. the first is the type constructor
# and the others are data constructors. It will
# return a tuple of the constructors in the same
# order.
Maybe, Just, None_ = adt("Maybe", "Just x", "None_")

# Here's how to use the maybe datatype
just1 = Just(1)
none = None_()

# __repr__ is provided by the dataclass
print(just1) # Just(x=1)

# isinstance relation is preserved
print(isinstance(just1, Maybe)) # True
print(type(just1) is Just) # True
print(type(none) is None_) # True
```

It works fine, BUT, if I use one of the generated types as a hint, mypy will complain about it not being a valid type

````
def foo(maybe: Maybe): ... # Variable "adt.Maybe" is not valid as a type
```

I tried to make `adt` returns `-> Iterable[type]` but it din't changed nothing. Not sure if there is a solution to this.
````

Comment: Have you made any effort to type-annotate your `adt` function?  Seems like if it returned a `Type` there'd be some chance of it working.

Comment: I tried with `Iterable[type]` I took a look on the mypy documentation for such topic but didn't find anything, I'm not very well versed on mypy too

Comment: I to use a typevar `t = TypeVar('T')` and then `-> Iterator[T]` this works, but I have some problems. Essentially I will return a list of classes where the first class is the superclass and the others are subclasses, these subclasses may have arbitrary number of arguments, if I return `T` the return becomes valid but not callable, if I return a callable I can't determine the number of arguments of each callalble, I'm start to thinking this is impossible except if there are dynamic features that I don't know in mypy

Comment: Yeah, I poked around at it a bit and I don't think it's doable -- to use something in a type annotation it seems like it needs to have a statically defined type.

Comment: You can always write a mypy plugin. Such a plugin exists for Django in order to accommodate all of its various type system shenanigans. I doubt there's too much in the way of documentation on that online, as it's not something most people need to do

Comment: What you can do is annotate as ``-> Iterable[Type[object]]:``, which basically means "returns a type". In practice this is useless since it gives no information about that type at all. You are better off defining ``class Just:`` and `class Nothing:` (e.g. via `@dataclass`) and then `Maybe = Just | Nothing`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this is usually what I do `class Maybe: ...; class Just(Maybe): ...`

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I didn't know that was possible to write mypy plugins, I will take a look on that, thanks!